# AutoQuery with a view

Tags: servicestack

How do I run a autoquery against a view instead of a table?

I created a alias for the object that has the view fields

[Alias("customer.vw_customer")]
    public class CustomerItem
    {
}
bbut i get the invalidobject error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing different needs to be done to access Views. Try without the prefix:

```
[Alias("vw_customer")] 
public class CustomerItem { ... }
```